# Problem with projection of layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I'm having a problem with projections in QGIS that I hope someone here can help me with. I have been searching and found other people having the same problem, but have not been able to solve mine based on those topics.

I have a shapefile, converted from a .SOSI file, and a .csv file made by me. Both layers are displayed, but they are two different places like shown in this picture:

[image: Picture]

I have also two pictures of the some general info of the shapefile and .csv file. Hope they can give some info.
[image: layer properties - test]
[image: layer properties - 02_admin...]

Hope you can help me out here, can't figure this out.

On the fly reprojection is enabled, I have tried to choose both same CRS and different CRS, nothing is working.

If you need any more info to solve this, just ask me and I will provide it.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates in the text file look like degrees, so you better set EPSG:4326 WGS84 for that layer.

If you are in doubt, change your project CRS to EPSG:3857, install the openlayers plugin and add a basemap from there. Then you can see which of your layers is placed right.

Or have a look at the metadata tab. If the entries for the extent are below +/-180/90, it surely is in degrees and not metres as used by UTM.

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by puting the 02_adminområder to UTM 33N and the .csv to 32N. And changing the coordinates for the .csv file, they was totally wrong :-P